# Plist NSPredicate in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, nspredicate

I have a plist working with a search display controller which contains an array of dictionaries with some data members like.

```
<root> (array)
  <"Item 0"> (dictionary)
    <"Name"></"Name" (String)
    <"Work"></"Work"> (String)
    <"Age"></"Work"> (Number)
  </"Item 0">
  <"Item 1">
    ....
  </"Item 1">
</root>
```

I would like to use an NSPredicate to filter all the names that match with the search criteria. For example searching "an" for all names will yield "Sandy" and "Alexander."

So far I've tried things like:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Name == %@",
                                filterText];
Results = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CONTAINS` in `NSPredicate`

Below code gives `case sensitive search`

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Name CONTAINS %@",
                            filterText];
Results = [yourPlistDataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```

Below code gives `case insensitive search`

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY Name CONTAINS %@",
                            filterText];
Results = [yourPlistDataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```

**EDIT** : Refer more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793-CJBDBHCB)

Comment: Looks like the predicate is malformed as it results in the error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or an NSSet.'

Answer (score 0):

this can show you the very generic type of the searching in any `NSArray`. it is adjusted to your `NSDictionary` items currently, but you can create even more complex conditions here to filter it.

```
NSArray *originalArray = ...;

NSString *searchText = ...; // this is a parameter only, it can be set freely

NSArray *_filteredArray = [originalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
            NSDictionary *_dataRow = (NSDictionary *)evaluatedObject;
            return ([[[_dataRow valueForKey:@"Name"] lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[searchText lowercaseString]].location != NSNotFound);
        }]];

NSLog (@"%@", _filteredArray);
```